# Question about relation between integral and summation in this case

Tags: definite-integrals

I have $N(t)=N_{\alpha_{n}}(t)=\#\lbrace n:\alpha_{n}\leq t\rbrace$.

Let $\{\alpha_{n}\}$ be a positive sequence, tending to infinity. Let $ \varphi (t) $ be a
differentiable, positive, and non-increasing function on $[1;0]$, such that $ \varphi (t)\rightarrow 0 $.

Why do we have: for any $ z\geq 1 $,

$$\sum_{k:\, 1\leq \alpha_{k}\leq z} \varphi (\alpha_{k})  = \int_1^z \varphi (t) dNt\,?$$
Why do they use $dN(t)$?

Comment: It is a Riemann–Stieltjes integral, right?

Comment: yes, this is a Riemann–Stieltjes integral. But why do they use $dN(t)$? I don't understand about the Riemann-Stieljes integral. Can you explain more?

Comment: By definition, $dN$ is a counting measure which adds $1$ each time $t$ encounters some value $\alpha$, hence the formula.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

You should use the integration by parts for the Riemann-Stieljes integral:

$$\int_1^z \varphi(t) dN(t)=\varphi(z) N(z) - \varphi(1) N(1)- \int_1^z \varphi^\prime(t) N(t)dt$$ And using the fact that $N$ is piecewise constant.

Comment: Why do they use $dN(t)$? I don't understand about the Riemann-Stieljes integral. Can you explain more?